# How to disable spring logging

Tags: spring, logging, disable

I  am working in a core java application and i recently added springintegration for TCP connection with my server.

I am using my own logger so I need to disable the spring logging. I have no logback xml, only an xml to have spring integration tcp connection.

How can I disable spring logging?

I already tried some stuffs in spring integration docs but doesn't work.
The spring logs are logging those for no use I already catches the errors and logs them but spring again does it of no use.

This is the file i am having for logging

```
# Logging Options
log.level           = INFO
log.path            = ./log/
log.console         = yes
log.backup.path     = ./log/bkp/
log.rotate.pattern  = yyyyMMddHH
log.org.springframework=OFF

# RawLog Logging Options
rawlog.path            = ./raw_log/
rawlog.backup.path     = ./raw_log/bkp/
rawlog.rotate.pattern  = yyyyMMddHH
```

Comment: Do you have a Spring related `.property` file?

Comment: no i have no property file